# Calling premailer manually isn't inlining styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, premailer

I'm working with Sendgrid's template system and need to manually inline some css for content that will be included in the Sendgrid smtpapi call.

Premailer doesn't seem to be actually inlining the css styles. I can inspect the result of calling `Premailer.new` but the processed_doc and doc both do not have the styles inlined.

Different methods I've tried:

#### Including the css file directly:

```
header = <<-HTML
  <div class="preview-content">
    #{data["content"]}
  </div>
HTML

p header
=>  "<div class=\"preview-content\">\n<p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the&nbsp;blind&nbsp;texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. </p>\n</div>\n"

premailer = Premailer.new(header, with_html_string: true, adapter: :nokogiri,css: [Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'stylesheets', 'email_base.css').to_s], input_encoding: "UTF-8", verbose: true)

p premailer.processed_doc.to_html
=> "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body>\n<div class=\"preview-content\">\n<p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the&nbsp;blind&nbsp;texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</p>\n</div>\n</body></html>\n"
```

`premailer.doc.to_html` returns the same thing with no inlined css.

I checked that the css file is accessible and that the styles apply to `.preview-content p`.

#### Adding a header to the document

```
header = <<-HTML
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->
    <title></title> <!-- The title tag shows in email notifications, like Android 4.4. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/asset/email_base.css" media="all">
  </head>
  <body width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin: 0; padding: 0 20px;">
    <div class="preview-content">
      #{data["content"]}
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
HTML

p header
=> '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n  <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\"> <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\"> <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->\n    <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\"> <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->\n    <title></title> <!-- The title tag shows in email notifications, like Android 4.4. -->\n    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/asset/email_base.css\" media=\"all\">\n  </head>\n  <body width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" bgcolor=\"#ffffff\" style=\"margin: 0; padding: 0 20px;\">\n    <div class=\"preview-content\">\n<p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the&nbsp;blind&nbsp;texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</p></div>\n  </body>\n  </html>\n'
```

The desired css to be inline:

```
.the-excerpt,
.the-excerpt p,
.preview-content p
  // +responsive-text(18px, 30px)
  line-height: 1.8 !important
  font-size: 18px
```

Is there something I'm missing to inline css manually? Both ways don't seem to yield any different results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying out [Premailer](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/premailer/Premailer) right now, and having some problems of my own.. but the way that i see Premailer actually processing the content and getting something different back (it removes the classes with the proper configuration setting, at least) is using this method:

```
premailer = Premailer.new(html, { :with_html_string=>true, :verbose=>true, :remove_classes=>true })
return premailer.to_inline_css
```

Comment: The issue I was running into was that Premailer can handle inlining html fragments, but can't make use of Rail's asset pipeline. The Rails premailer is smart enough to compile scss into css before inlining but doesnt support fragments.